# How to use navigation.navigate from a component outside the stack.navigation

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I have an application using React native where I am using react-navigation (5.2.9).

I built a Stack.Navigator where I've got my screens but I want the Footer component to be outside so it renders in all screens. The problem is, I can't navigate from the footer, which is what I need to do as the footer has a few buttons that should be changing the screen:

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const App = () => {    
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Header />
        <Stack.Navigator>
          <Stack.Screen
            name="Home"
            component={HomeScreen}
            options={{
            headerShown: false
          }}
          />
          <Stack.Screen
            name="Login"
            component={LoginScreen}
            options={{
            headerShown: false
          }}
          />
        </Stack.Navigator>
        <Footer />
      </NavigationContainer>
    </Provider>
  );
};
```

How do I pass the navigation prop to the footer component?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Try this:

Create a new file named: RootNavigation.js

```js
// RootNavigation.js

import * as React from 'react';

export const navigationRef = React.createRef();

export function navigate(name, params) {
  navigationRef.current?.navigate(name, params);
}
```

```js
// file where you have the navigation

import {navigationRef} from './path/to/RootNavigation';

      <NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef}>
      .....
        <Footer />
      </NavigationContainer>
```

And Footer.js should be something like this:

```js
// Footer.js

import React from 'react';
import {View, Button} from 'react-native';
import * as RootNavigation from './path/to/RootNavigation';

const Footer= () => {
  return (
    <View>
      <Button
        title={'Go to'}
        onPress={() =>
          RootNavigation.navigate('screenName ', {userName: 'Lucy'})
        }
      />
    </View>
  );
};

export default Footer;
```

For more info you can read the documentation. https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating-without-navigation-prop/

Comment: Is this not literally what I answered, a day before?

Comment: Thank youu, exactly what i was looking for :D

Comment: Will this work if the file which I'm using the navigation in is not a component/screen ? As in, if it is not wrapped by `NavigationContainer` ?

What I'm trying to achieve is to navigate to a particular screen when a notification is received. (I'm using `react-native-push-notification` for this.) But the configuration for push notifications is not to be added in any component; it should be in a separate file.

Comment: ref.current is always null. I log it in setInterval and it does not get initialized. Why?

Comment: Well, i typed navigationRef={navigationRef} instead of ref={navigationRef}. Two hours gone on that. oh god :/

Comment: Finally I got a working solution. Thank you.

Comment: @how can i use CommonActions.reset() this way?

Comment: this solution doesn't work for unmounted screens

Answer (score 23):

The components outside of the `Stack.Screen` components do not receive the navigation prop. So in this case, you have to get the `NavigationContainer` using refs in your footer component, as follows:

1. Create a ref with `const myRef = React.createRef()`
2. pass it to the `<NavigationContainer ref={myRef}>`, and
3. use that ref to navigate, `myRef.current?.navigate(name, params)`.

It is all explained [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating-without-navigation-prop). The docs here separate the creation of the ref in a new file, to allow you to import the ref without dependency loops/ issues. As the docs state, you can now call `RootNavigation.navigate('ChatScreen', { userName: 'Lucy' });` in any js module, not just in a react component.

In your case though, you don't need the ref in separate file.

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const navigationRef = React.createRef();

const App = () => {    
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef}>
        <Header />
        <Stack.Navigator>
          <Stack.Screen
            name="Home"
            component={HomeScreen}
            options={{
            headerShown: false
          }}
          />
          <Stack.Screen
            name="Login"
            component={LoginScreen}
            options={{
            headerShown: false
          }}
          />
        </Stack.Navigator>
        <Footer navigationRef={navigationRef}/>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </Provider>
  );
};
```

And in `<Footer/>` use `navigationRef.current?.navigate(name, params)`

Comment: I find this is much easier to follow that the approved answer

Answer (score 9):

From the documentation.
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/connecting-navigation-prop/

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Button } from 'react-native';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

function GoToButton({ screenName }) {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  return (
    <Button
      title={`Go to ${screenName}`}
      onPress={() => navigation.navigate(screenName)}
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: Obviously I have tried what documentation says but this will only show the following error: Couldn't find a navigation.object, Is your component inside a screen in a navigator?

Comment: Using the same method, still getting the same error.

Answer (score 3):

A simple trick to extract `navigation` out of `screenOptions`.

```
function NavWrapper() {
  const navigatorRef = useRef<any>();
  <Tab.Navigator
    screenOptions={({ navigation: nav }) => navigatorRef.current = nav}
  >
    <Tab.Screen name="screen1" />
  </Tab.Navigator>
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I ended up building a component called screen that will just wrap the content of screen and render the header/footer based on props:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View } from 'native-base';
import style from './style';
import Footer from '../../footer';
import Header from '../../header';

const Screen = ({
    footer,
    header,
    children,
    navigation
}) => (
  <View style={style.screen}>
    { header && <Header navigation={navigation} />}
    { children }
    { footer && <Footer navigation={navigation} />}
  </View>
);

export default Screen;
```

And wrapping the screens of my apps like this:

```
<Screen header footer navigation={navigation}>
    ... screen content
</Screen>
```

I feel like it is the best way if I can't sort that problem out.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem with a global state using React context API:

```
  // When enter in the HomeScreen:
  const { setGlobalNavigation, globalNavigation } = useGlobalContext();
  const navigation = useNavigation<RemindersNavigationProp>();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (setGlobalNavigation && !globalNavigation) setGlobalNavigation(navigation);
  }, [setGlobalNavigation, globalNavigation, navigation]);

  // When want to use:
  const { globalNavigation } = useGlobalContext();
  const handleNavigate = () => 
  globalNavigation.navigate("contactsStack", { screen: "newContact" });
```

Answer (score 0):

Typescript-safe way:

Use `CommonActions`

```
import { createNavigationContainerRef  } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { CommonActions } from '@react-navigation/native';


export const navigationRef = createNavigationContainerRef()

export function navigate(routeName: string, params?: object) {
    if (navigationRef.isReady()) {
      navigationRef.dispatch(CommonActions.navigate(routeName, params));
    }
}
```